Accidentally moved slack history from one conversation to another. How can I move back?
I started a conversation today with multiple people on Slack on iOS and there was a prompt that asked if I wanted to include history. I chose yes and it moved the chat history I had with 1 person, to the conversation that was newly created with 3 people.
How can I move the chat history back?

This happened to me to.  I wanted to go to a DM with 3 people.  I typed the first name in, and then added the other two, and it asked if I wanted to start with fresh history or keep everything to date.  I didn't realize it meant the "everything to date" that I had in the private DM with that first person, so I selected that.  It then moved all of that conversation into the DM we already have with the other two people.  Fortunately, there wasn't anything embarrassing there, but that seems like a terrible feature with currently very ambiguous messaging.

this is a completely insane "feature," this should not be possible without explicit intent, and clicking OK to a vaguely worded dialog box you're not expecting is not it
